# Storing Amazon's product API data in database

Tags: amazon-product-api

I am trying to build an application with retail data from US but experiment in India. I want to put in new features like group shopping and also analyze user behavior like buying, sharing etc.

But, I want data from Amazon and other affiliates. I am thinking if to store Amazon's data in my database without images being downloaded (as per its terms).

But, I am not clear at all from their terms if I can store the API results in my database and update regularly. I wouldn't want the whole of Amazon data though! Just a sample, like 20-30K products.

Is this allowed? Has anyone done this?

Link to terms - https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/agreement.html

Answer (score 0):

You can store them on your DB for up to 24 hours.So, when you receive a request for a specific product,

1. First check if it has been updated within 24 hours since the last updated time.
2. If it has, simply use the data from the DB. Otherwise, fetch the latest data from the amazon and store it on the DB to use for the next 24 hours period.